# Fastest possible way to transfer a large directory over VPN

Tags: file-upload, compression

I have a problem. Everyday I have to upload my whole source code (it is a directory with several directories and files) to a server over VPN. The size of source code is around 250 MB. What I do everyday is, compress it (that reduces it's size to around 100 MB), then I transfer this zipped file over ftp to the server and finally unzip it there. It takes me around 20 minutes to transfer that.
I am sure there has got to be a better way of doing this than what I am doing. Either suggest me a better compression mechanism or faster upload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could set up a Version Control server it would be great, Mercurial and Git are perfect for this.

The other option is using rsync, which is a synchronizing tool that only uploads the differences between the two versions, avoiding repetitive transmission of data.

I'm assuming a UNIX-like environment here, but on windows the options are pretty much the same.

PD: this question is more fitted for [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the super-fast response. I never thought of syncing as an option. (The environments are Unix, your assumption is right)

Comment: If all you need is the last version of the code to be in the remote location then syncing will fit, however if you need "every" version then a DVCS is the way to go.